# Answer deleted 14 months after posting

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

A moderator deleted my answer on [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57715/standard-visitor-visa-refusal-deception-v3-6b-and-procedure-for-reapplying?rq=1) 14 months after it was written, and despite 13 up votes.

I realize that the answer was skeptical of the OP's presentation of the issue, in which he "forgot" his mother's arrest and negotiated plea. There were comments on this at the time.

Comment: What is the question? Would you like it to be undeleted?

Comment: Yes. And I am not sure there is value in deleting so long after the answer is posted.

Answer (score -2):

Answers can be deleted at any time if they [do not fundamentally answer the question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). There is no time limit on when a moderator or other users may do so.

If you believe you have a better answer feel free to improve your original post and it will be undeleted.